# I want to show either creditcardpage of paypal or Paypallogin page (account login).how can i do it in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing an application where in i have a registration page where people will be asked whether they will pay by paypal account or creditcard process.
if paypal account selected then the paypal page should only show paypal login page (no credit card page)
if credit card process-then it should only show only Credit card page where you have to enter firstname,lastname,credit card noetc but no paypal account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PayPal Express Checkout, you can specify LANDINGPAGE=Billing or LANDINGPAGE=Login in your initial SetExpressCheckout API call to force a specific page to be displayed.

Further reading: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout